# MongoDB $match in regex does not work gives an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document like:

```json
{
  id: string,
  blogCover:{ title: string }, 
  published: boolean
}
```

I am using $regex to create a search system as follows:

```js
    app.post('/searchblogs',(req,res)=>{
    var searchfield = req.body.query;

    TFBlog.find({"blogCover.title":{
      $regex:searchfield,
      $options:'$i'
    }}).then((docs)=>{
     res.send(docs);
    });

    });
```

Now I want search results to only include documents with **published:true**

I used $match like

```js
    TFBlog.find({"blogCover.title":{

      $match : { published : true },
      $regex:searchfield,
      $options:'$i'

    }}).then((docs)=>{
     res.send(docs);
    });
```

This gives an error :

```
(node:16304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't use $match with String.
```

What should I do ? is there any alternative to achieve this???

Answer (score 2):

`$match` is a stage in `aggregate()` query, and it can not be used in `find()`. Change your code like this:

```js
TFBlog.find({
  "blogCover.title": { $regex: searchfield, $options: 'i' },
  "published": true
}).then((docs) => {
  res.send(docs);
});
```